# Does quantum entangled particle release energy when its "twin" is measured?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, information

So I was just thinking a bit, and I came up with a couple of questions.

As we all know the scenario:
We have two quantum entangled particles. Let's call them **A** and **B**.
We like to measure the state of **A** which will instantly
affect **B**.

Many people wonder if that could be used for communication, and the answer is NO.

At least not in a direct way, or any indirect way that we know of.

What I'm wondering is if **B** will release any
kind of energy when **A** is measured?

If yes, what kind of energy and on what level?

Would it be on a quantum mechanical level?

Would there be any ripple effects on the quantum foam when a quantum entangled particle is affected?

Could the quantum foam around a particle be measured and monitored
rather than the particle itself?

I'm no physicist, but I'm seriously thinking of starting to read about these things.

Comment: you changed the questions but the answers are the same

Comment: What? I changed the title of the question as well as changed the references "entangled particle" and "twin" and similar references to "A" and "B". So the question remains the same, but the understandability is better now.

Comment: Why would B "release energy"? It's not clear to me how you came up with this question, or what answer except "No, why would it?" you expect.

Comment: Well, because when you "energize" A further in order to measure it, right. So if you need to insert more energy in order to measure A, either A or B need to release energy for you to measure it. Some of that energy might maybe be released by B since both A and B are entangled. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

If B released energy when A was measured, you could use it for communication. And you *know* the answer to "Can entanglement be used for communication?" is NO. You mentioned it in your question! Therefore...

**No**, entangled particles don't release energy when their partner is measured. They don't change *in any locally determinable way* when their partner is measured or disturbed or even left alone (with the exception that when you compare notes later there can be some interesting correlations).

Answer (score 1):

If the particles are nontrivially entangled, then particle $A$ cannot be in an eigenstate of the energy operator (or any other operator that acts just on $A$'s state space) in the first place.

If the initial entangled state is, say, $X\otimes Y+Z\otimes W$, where (for example) $X$ and $Z$ are energy eigenstates, then an observation of particle $B$ will change the state of particle $A$ to either $X$ or $Z$ ---- but you cannot know which, and if you now measure the energy of particle $A$, you're going to get either $X$ or $Z$ with exactly the same probabilities as you would have before you did your measurement on $B$.

So there is no reasonable interpretation under which $A$ can possibly "emit energy" at the time when $B$ is measured, at least if "emitting energy" refers to any phenomenon that can, at least in principle, be observed.

Comment: Hmmm... The last 3 rows of your explanation: What I meant was if B will emit energy when A is measured.

Comment: I addressed the question of whether $A$ will emit energy when $B$ is measured.  If you prefer the opposite labels, it shouldn't be too hard to change the $A$'s to $B$'s and vice versa.

Comment: Oh ok I got the impression that you were talking about measuring A as well as A emitting energy.

Comment: BUT! If I understand the idea of quantum entanglement correctly, energy is used to put A and B in an entangled state, so essentially observing A must mean that B affects its environment.  I know I know, there's really nothing around particles it's more or less 99.999999 empty space, but some energy has to be converted somehow in order to make B assume the same state as A. And that energy has to go somewhere. Right? maybe a super short burst of an electromagnetic signal or something. I don't know, I just need to read more about this.

Comment: Again:  Ask yourself what it means for a particle to "emit energy" when it's not in an energy eigenstate to begin with.

Comment: *"If the particles are nontrivially entangled, then particle A cannot be in an eigenstate of the energy operator (or any other operator that acts just on A's state space) in the first place."* -- Only if the energy operator is non-degenerate.